# Openstack provider network unable to connect to internet or external network

Tags: networking, ip, openstack

I have a controller and a compute node. I did a complete step by step installation of Victoria on Ubuntu 20.04. Configured a 192.168.4.x ip for controller and compute on eno1 interface. And also configured eno2 interface for compute as provider interface.
Installation was successful and I can create new networks, instances and assign network and floating ip's to instances. These instances can interact on same and different internal networks on OpenStack.

But when I make provider network of a selective pool from 192.168.73.x/29 and assign floating ip's from this network, this floating ip is supposed to be accessible from controller as well as from external network but its not.
Further it can't even ping the gateway 192.168.73.1.

Please guide me on this and if you need any other info or output, please let me know.Thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Ok so my interface for the provider network was not up and I had not even connected a cable to it (was confused if that was needed)

Now the communication is happening

FYI: The management network provides communication for the nodes and the provider network provides communication for the instances with external network and with internet.